# Using mysql from Perl in an Azure web app

Tags: mysql, perl, azure, fastcgi, strawberry-perl

I am using Azure to host a site which uses Perl and MySql. I have placed all my Strawberry perl files in the bin folder. I connect to Perl by adding a handler to the Perl executable which is located on my web app in d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\perl\bin\perl.exe.

I can run simple Perl programs ok. However when I try to run a Perl script which connects to a MySql database I get the following error:

install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load 'D:/home/site/wwwroot/bin/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.xs.dll' for module DBD::mysql: load_file:The specified module could not be found at D:/home/site/wwwroot/bin/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.

However mysql.xs.dll exists in that location. I have also copied into the same folder as mysql.xs.dll the file libmysql_.dll which I read somewhere was a dependency of mysql.xs.dll.

The datasource I am trying to get to looks like this:

```
my $data_source = "DBI:mysql:$database:$hostname";
```

I am using the same code and binary files as handlers for Perl in my local IIS so I think all the files needed are there in my bin folder.

What else can I try?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/DBD::mysql), you should use `database=$database:host=$hostname`

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because I have used the same code on my local PC and in a LAMP environment and it worked. There error message indicates a problem with executable locations so I think that is what I need to solve.

Comment: How did you install the dlls?

Comment: I installed them on my Windows PC and copied the C:\Strawberry folder and everything  beneath it on my PC to the bin folder at 'D:/home/site/wwwroot/bin' folder

Comment: Are you sure your PC has the same architecture and system as the target system? I'd rather install the software properly.

Comment: Because it's a web app I don't have access to the whole environment so you can't really install software. I can control whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit Windows on the web app. Plan B is to use a virtual machine instead where I can do that but I really wanted to get it working on a web app.

Comment: backslash or slash? That aside, you could provide modules with http://perlbrew.pl/. That is a much better approach to be somewhat independent of the system you want to deploy to.